# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread BasePostCell.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have crash from crashlytics, can you tell where is the reason for this? Does it connected to the AuthManager or to the BasePostCell?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  goForDream                     0x1023f22ac BasePostCell.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) + 4304741036 (<compiler-generated>:4304741036)
1  goForDream                     0x1023f2340 @objc BasePostCell.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) + 4304741184 (<compiler-generated>:4304741184)
2  UIKitCore                      0x19ae22d00 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 444
3  UIKitCore                      0x19ae249c8 -[UICollectionView _prefetchItemsForPrefetchingContext:maxItemsToPrefetch:] + 476
4  UIKitCore                      0x19ae2c4fc -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 1020
5  UIKitCore                      0x19baa48b0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2156
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x197204a4c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 68
7  QuartzCore                     0x19e0ba55c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 292
8  QuartzCore                     0x19e0ba9ac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 484
9  QuartzCore                     0x19e0cd1bc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140
10 QuartzCore                     0x19e011b00 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 308
11 QuartzCore                     0x19e03c910 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684
12 QuartzCore                     0x19e03d4e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 96
13 CoreFoundation                 0x19746b524 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1974661c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420
15 CoreFoundation                 0x197466774 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292
16 CoreFoundation                 0x197465f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
17 GraphicsServices               0x1a16f6534 GSEventRunModal + 108
18 UIKitCore                      0x19b5f1580 UIApplicationMain + 1940
19 goForDream                     0x1021a03a8 main + 26 (AuthManager.swift:26)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1972e4e18 start + 4
```

CollectionViewDelegate code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return assets.count == 1 ? 0 : assets.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as FeedPostCarouselCollectionViewCell
    if !assets.isEmpty {
        let photo = assets[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: photo)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This crash suggest that the issue in making cell in cellForItemAt delegate method, So first you try to regenerate this issue, that give more detail about crash

Comment: I can't reproduce it on device or simulator.

Comment: Share your collection view delegate code

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology If you show the reason of the crash printed in console log here, it would be great!

Comment: Crash will not generated but i think issue in the cell in this line "collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as FeedPostCarouselCollectionViewCell" the correct method is that "let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeedPostCarouselCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedPostCarouselCollectionViewCell"

Comment: Thanks, but method is correct, it's just generic:   func dequeueReusableCell<T: UIView>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView {
    guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(identifier: T.ml_reuseIdentifier, indexPath: indexPath) as? T else {
      fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.ml_reuseIdentifier)")
    }
    return cell
  }

Comment: Since the crash logs indicates that `BasePostCell` crashes, either you did not register the cell  for the collection view, or something is wrong with the cell. It tries to dequeue, but fails. Some more code is needed, since the crash indicates on BasePostCell, but you paste the code which uses FeedPostCarouselCollectionViewCell

Comment: When you initialize the cell using `let cell =`... shouldn't you specify a reuse identifier? When you register a cell when you initialize the `collectionView`, you specify a reuse identifier, even for a generic `UICollectionViewCell`. I am not sure how you were able to compile your project without it giving you the error: `Missing argument for parameter 'withReuseIdentifier' in call`